# Using Django cache.add for locking in a celery task is not working

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a celery task that has a critical section of code that I'm trying to protect using the [Ensuring a task is only executed one at a time](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time) recipe, which leverages Django's caching framework.

I threw it in a little `contextmanager` so my code looks like this:

```
BIG_TASK_LOCK = 'BIG_TASK_LOCK'

def big_task_lock():
    while not cache.add(BIG_TASK_LOCK, 'true', 30):
        logger.info("Waiting on big task lock which is currently {}...".format(
            cache.get(BIG_TASK_LOCK)
        ))
        time.sleep(1)
    logger.info("Got big task lock!")


def big_task_unlock():
    logger.info("big task unlock")
    cache.delete(BIG_TASK_LOCK)


@contextmanager
def big_task_locked():
    big_task_lock()
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        big_task_unlock()

@app.task(bind=True)
def my_task(self):
    ...
    with big_task_locked():
        # critical section
```

With this code I would have expected to only see the lock/unlock print statements from a single process, without any interleaving locks from other processes.  However, I'm seeing that multiple workers are managing to grab the lock concurrently:

```
INFO 2016-06-15 16:40:38,307 pid=1657 fn=big_task_lock Waiting on big task lock which is currently true...
INFO 2016-06-15 16:40:38,450 pid=1654 fn=big_task_lock Got big task lock!
INFO 2016-06-15 16:40:38,461 pid=1658 fn=big_task_lock Waiting on big task lock which is currently true...
INFO 2016-06-15 16:40:38,501 pid=1659 fn=big_task_lock Waiting on big task lock which is currently true...
INFO 2016-06-15 16:40:38,517 pid=1660 fn=big_task_unlock big task unlock
INFO 2016-06-15 16:40:38,808 pid=1661 fn=big_task_lock Got big task lock!
INFO 2016-06-15 16:40:39,035 pid=1662 fn=big_task_lock Waiting on big task lock which is currently true...
INFO 2016-06-15 16:40:39,172 pid=1640 fn=big_task_unlock big task unlock
INFO 2016-06-15 16:40:39,175 pid=1647 fn=big_task_lock Got big task lock!
INFO 2016-06-15 16:40:39,311 pid=1657 fn=big_task_lock Waiting on big task lock which is currently true...
INFO 2016-06-15 16:40:39,465 pid=1658 fn=big_task_lock Waiting on big task lock which is currently true...
INFO 2016-06-15 16:40:39,513 pid=1659 fn=big_task_lock Got big task lock!
INFO 2016-06-15 16:40:39,684 pid=1663 fn=big_task_lock Waiting on big task lock which is currently true...
INFO 2016-06-15 16:40:40,039 pid=1662 fn=big_task_lock Got big task lock!
INFO 2016-06-15 16:40:40,317 pid=1657 fn=big_task_lock Waiting on big task lock which is currently true...
INFO 2016-06-15 16:40:40,347 pid=1660 fn=big_task_lock Waiting on big task lock which is currently true...
INFO 2016-06-15 16:40:40,470 pid=1658 fn=big_task_lock Got big task lock!
```

Look at all of those "Got big task lock" messages in a row without any interleaving unlocks!  How is that happening??  Is it just the logs from different processes being flushed out at different times, or is there a race condition in here that I'm missing?

I'm using Postgres 9.3, Django 1.9, and Celery 3.1.23.

Comment: What cache backend are you using?

Comment: Hmm I'm using a database backend with postgres. I assumed that was capable of atomic add by using row-level locking although I haven't looked at the implementation.

Comment: @mgalgs Looking at the implementation of the database cache backend (`_base_set` method), I see opportunities for race conditions there too. The only locking happens with `UPDATE` and `INSERT`. (The initial `SELECT` does not lock because it is not `FOR UPDATE`.) It would be possible to have processes A and B get to just before the `UPDATE`, process A completes its transaction, then process B resumes and performs its own update without problem because the lock held by A was released. (When I say "lock", I'm talking about database locks, not the lock you're trying to implement.)

Comment: Interesting... I'll take a look myself a bit later. Are there any cache backends that are actually suitable for this sort of locking? Looks like the filesystem backend isn't but the memcached backend might be. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @mgalgs I've used a cache backed with Redis (through the `django-redis` package) and used `cache.set(key, <value>, nx=True)` to do something similar to what you are trying to do. The `nx=True` parameter makes it so that the `set` will occur only if there was not already a value and it is done atomically.

Comment: Switched to `memcached` and it totally works as expected now.